# Windows Automated Installation. How can I change boot order in WinPE from a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, bcdedit, winpe

Trying to complete automated install of windows OS. I have WinPe on a USB which is first in boot order. I have several batch files running automatically in WinPE making partitions etc. as part of the automated setup.

I would like to have an automated script to change the boot order at the end of the process so the machine does not keep booting into WinPE on the USB.

I would like a script to change the boot order to perhaps option 2 so it boots into the C drive so the OS boots up meaning it can be totally unattended.

I know I probably have to change bcdboot or bcdedit but what must I change? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the OS from a reinstall loop i added a 'PAUSE' to 'Press any key to continue' at the end of the installation and a message 'REMOVE USB INSTALLATION MEDIA'